# Seaborn scatterplot with varying marker sizes and informative legend

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot, marker

I'm trying to create a scatterplot in which the size of the markers vary according to the values of specific columns in the dataframe. This can be done with `size` and the size of the markers may be scaled using `sizes`. However, when creating the appropriate legend, three problems arise. The following is a simple example:

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.normal(size=10),
                   'y1': np.random.normal(size=10),
                   'y2': 2 + np.random.normal(size=10),                      
                   'p':  np.random.uniform(size=10),
                   'q': np.random.uniform(size=10)})

# Note that `y2` has been shifted but this is on purpose as it will be useful below.
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7), tight_layout=True)

axs = sns.scatterplot(data = df_ex, x='x',y='y1', size='p',label = 'Y1')
axs = sns.scatterplot(data = df_ex, x='x',y='y2', size='q',label = 'Y2')

axs.set_xlabel('X')
axs.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.show()
```

[image]

First, the legend presents both the original label of the series of interest (that defines the vertical axis) and the variable that defines the size of the markers. In the example below, this is shown both as `Y1` and `Y2`, the labels of the variables that define the vertical axis, and `p` and `q` that define the marker size for each variable `y1` and `y2`, respectively. I would like to just show `Y1` and `Y2` in the legend, without referring to `p` and `q`, but still showing the different marker sizes and the associated values in the legend (in other words, take the same legend that the plot currently shows and delete `p` and `q`).

Second, in the legend the marker sizes are all presented in black. I would like to use the same color as the one used to show `Y1` and `Y2` (that correspond to the colors used in the plot).

Third, is there a way that the two series can use the same marker size standardization so a marker of a specific size represents the same underlying values across series? In the plot, each series has its own standardization that depends on the values in the columns `y1` and `y2` in the dataframe. However, in some cases it may be necessary for the marker size to be defined considering both series jointly, and not individually as it is currently being done.

Comment: `rate_p = df_ex.p.tolist();axs = sns.scatterplot(data=df_ex, x='x', y='y1', hue=rate_p, label='Y1')`Try to modify Y1 and Y2 using the same technique respectively. Is the result what you want?

Comment: I don't think so. Doing this doesn't impact the size of the markers, just the color, and the scale that defines the gradient is different for Y1 and Y2 (the same color corresponds to a different value in each variable).

Comment: I also tried creating two dataframes (`dfe1 = df_ex[['x','y1','p']]` and `dfe2 = df_ex[['x','y2','q']]`), then renaming `y1` and `y2` as `Y`, and `p` and `q` as `s`, and adding a categorical variable that identified each dataframe (`dfe1['ind']=1` and `dfe2['ind']=2`), and then appending them and plotting indexing based on the categorical variable (e.g., `data=dfe[dfe['ind']==1]` and `data=dfe[dfe['ind']==2]`), but this also defined the scale of `s` separately for each plot and repeated the problem in the legend showing both the labels `Y1` and `Y2` and the label `s`, so it didn't work.